# bash- searching for a string in a file and returning all the matching positions

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, fasta

I have a fasta file_imagine as a txt file in which even lines are sequences of characters and odd lines are sequence id's_ I would like to search for a string in sequences and get the  position for matching substrings as well as their ids. Example:
Input:

```
>111
AACCTTGG
>222
CTTCCAACC
>333
AATCG
```

search for "CC" . output:

```
3 111
4 8 222
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'CC' 'NR%2==1{id=substr($0,2);next} NF>1{x=1+length($1); b=x; for (i=2;i<NF;i++){x+=length(FS $i); b=b " " x}; print b,id}' file
3 111
4 8 222
```

Explanation:

- `-F'CC'`

  awk breaks input lines into fields.  We instruct it to use the sequence of interest, `CC` in this example, as the field separator.
- `NR%2==1{id=substr($0,2);next}`

  On odd number lines, we save the id to variable `id`.  The assumption is that the first character is `>` and the id is whatever comes after.  Having captured the id, we instruct awk to skip the remaining commands and start over with the `next` line.
- `NF>1{x=1+length($1); b=x; for (i=2;i<NF;i++){x+=length(FS $i); b=b " " x}; print b,id}`

  If awk finds only one field on an input line, `NF==1`, that means that there were no field separators found and we ignore those lines.

  For the rest of the lines, we calculate the positions of each match in `x` and then save each value of `x` found in the string `b`.

  Finally, we print the match locations, `b`, and the `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Will print line number and the position of each start of each match.

```
awk 'NR%2==1{t=substr($0,2)}{z=a="";while(y=match($0,"CC")){a=a?a" "z+y:z+y;$0=substr($0,z=(y+RLENGTH));z-=1}}a{print a,t }' file
```

Neater

```
awk '
NR%2==1{t=substr($0,2)}
    {
    z=a=""
    while ( y = match($0,"CC") ) {
        a=a?a" "z+y:z+y
        $0=substr($0,z=(y+RLENGTH))
        z-=1
    }
}
a { print a,t }' file
```

.

```
3 111
4 8 222
```